# How to skip static(hardcoded entry) entry in PostgreSQL if value is NULL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have written following query for data retrieval in Jasper report.

```
select d.description as description,d.upload_count as count
from
(select a.doc_type,b.description,count(*) as upload_count
from case_uploads a,doc_type b
where a.doc_type = b.doc_type
and a.upload_dt >= $P{START_DATE}
and a.upload_dt <= $P{END_DATE}
group by a.doc_type,b.description) d
where d.doc_type not in ('215','F35')

union all

select 'Applications' as description,SUM(d.upload_count) as count
from
(select a.doc_type,b.description,count(*) as upload_count
from case_uploads a,doc_type b
where a.doc_type = b.doc_type
and a.upload_dt >= $P{START_DATE}
and a.upload_dt <= $P{END_DATE}
group by a.doc_type,b.description) d
where d.doc_type in ('215','F35')
```

Here, in my database I have data for June 2015 only. If my start_date and end_date are from any month other than June.

So in this case I don't want to display any data in my result set. But as my query contains 'Applications' as hard coded value, its adding an entry in result set with NULL value.

```
 description     count
------------------------
Applications     null
```

Because of this null value, jasper report throwing "Null pointer exception" after execution.

I want to skip this entry if data is not retrieved. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `where d.doc_type not in ('215','F35') and count IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MatchesMalone That'd work if you wrap the whole query up as a subquery and put the predicate on the outside, yes. Otherwise use a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @MatchesMalone No Its not working

Comment: @CraigRinger o yeah, thanks! OP please try to run the answer I've written below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the comments, you can use this:

```
select d.description as description,d.upload_count as count
from
(select a.doc_type,b.description,count(*) as upload_count
from case_uploads a,doc_type b
where a.doc_type = b.doc_type
and a.upload_dt >= $P{START_DATE}
and a.upload_dt <= $P{END_DATE}
group by a.doc_type,b.description) d
where d.doc_type not in ('215','F35')
and d.upload_count IS NOT NULL

union all

select 'Applications' as description,SUM(d.upload_count) as count
from
(select a.doc_type,b.description,count(*) as upload_count
from case_uploads a,doc_type b
where a.doc_type = b.doc_type
and a.upload_dt >= $P{START_DATE}
and a.upload_dt <= $P{END_DATE}
group by a.doc_type,b.description) d
where d.doc_type in ('215','F35')
having SUM(d.upload_count) IS NOT NULL
```